# table sorting javascript using select option menu

Tags: php, javascript, html, sorting

I tried to sort some data which is retrieve from database

Firstly, the user will choose which country's data they want to show from select option menu

after that, the next page will show the particular data in the table with the sort asc/desc function

this is my code

first page test.html

```
<form action="showDB1.php" method="post">
<table border="0">
<tr>
    <th colspan="3">test</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Select Foreign Agent Country</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
    <select name="country">
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="JP">Japan</option>
    </select> 
    </td>
  </tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value-"Submit">
    </td>
</table>
</form>
```

this is my code to show the data after the user chose which country's data they want to show showDB1.php

```
<?php
//connect to server
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

//connect to database
//select the database
mysql_select_db("fak_databases");
//submit button
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{
    $country = $_POST['country'];
}

//query the database
if($country == TRUE) {
    $order = "";
    $sort = "asc"; 
    $sql = "SELECT wipo_applicant1_city, applicant1_addr1 FROM auip_wipo_sample";
    if(isset($_GET['orderby'])){
        $order = $_GET['orderby']; 
        $sort = $_GET['sort'];  

        //limiting the possible values of order/sort variables
        if($order != 'wipo_applicant1_city' && $order != 'applicant1_addr1')$order = "applicant1_addr1";
            if($sort != 'asc' && $sort != 'desc')$sort = "asc";
                $sql = "SELECT wipo_applicant1_city, applicant1_addr1 FROM auip_wipo_sample WHERE applicant1_country='$country' ORDER BY ".mysql_real_escape_string($order)." ".$sort; 

                //here we reverse the sort variable
                if($sort == "asc"){
                    $sort = "desc";
                }
            else{
                $sort = "asc";
            }
        }
    // query to get all US records   
} 
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $row_counter = 0; 

    $icon = "";
    echo "<table  border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n";
    echo "<tr>\n"; 

    // first column
    echo "<th>";
    $icon = "";
    if($order == "wipo_applicant1_city"){
        if($sort == "asc"){
            $icon = "<img src=\"images/up.png\" class=\"arrowSpace\"/>";
        }
        if($sort == "desc"){
            $icon = "<img src=\"images/down.png\" class=\"arrowSpace\"/>";
        }
    }

    //print the result
    echo "<a href='index.php?orderby=wipo_applicant1_city&sort=".$sort."'>City</a>".$icon;
    echo "</th>\n";


    // second column
    echo "<th>";
    $icon = "";
    if($order == "applicant1_addr1"){
        if($sort == "asc"){
            $icon = "<img src=\"images/up.png\" class=\"arrowSpace\"/>";
        }
        if($sort == "desc"){
            $icon = "<img src=\"images/down.png\" class=\"arrowSpace\"/>";
        }
    }
    echo "<a href='index.php?orderby=applicant1_addr1&sort=".$sort."'>Address</a>".$icon;
    echo "</th>\n";
    echo "</tr>";

//fetch the result

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row_counter % 2){
            $row_color="bgcolor='#FFFFFF'";
        }else{
            $row_color="bgcolor='#F3F6F8'";
        }
    echo "<tr class=\"TrColor\" ".$row_color.">";
    echo "<td>" . $row['wipo_applicant1_city'] . "</td>\n";
    echo "<td>" . $row['applicant1_addr1'] . "</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>";
    $row_counter++;
}

Print "</table>";
```

my problem is all the data is shown when the user choose any country of the select option.

the expected result should be only particular data need to be shown

anyone can fix this?

thanks

Comment: nice sql injection hole... (you forgot to escape $country and $sort...)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @MarcB....I'm just a newbie in this area....anw, thanks for response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at your code, the problem might be that you have a dash instead of an equal sign in your input button

```
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value-"Submit">
```

should be

```
value="Submit"
```

---

I would look at the following if statement then

```
if(isset($_GET['orderby'])){
```

Since in your initial submission of your form you are sending post statements, your sql statement is not being called as it is wrapped inside in that if statement.

Move the following outside that statement

```
$order = "";
$sort = "asc"; 
$sql = "SELECT wipo_applicant1_city, applicant1_addr1 FROM auip_wipo_sample";
```

and of course add this for your country selection to show up

```
 WHERE applicant1_country='$country'
```

Comment: no problem i made an edit to my answer that hopefully has the fix that you are looking for to make your code work

Comment: is it just like what I edited in the code...I move the code just like you suggest to below if($country == TRUE) {....if so, I got 2 errors which are mysql_num_rows() and mysql_fetch_array()...both expect 1 paramater...anyway, thanks for helping me until now :)

Comment: hmm, if it was my code, i would move $sql variable temporarily to above the line that you are calling mysql_num_rows on and see if it still throws an error and then go from there.

Comment: everything is done...I just did a silly mistake on my $sql...I put WHERE statement first before FROM statement...

Comment: awesome, glad you got it all sorted out